# converting curl -x get to vb.net without success

Tags: vb.net, curl

I need to convert this to vb.net:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'X-API-KEY: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 'https://app.atera.com/api/v3/agents'
```

What I've tried is:

```
Dim myHttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://app.atera.com/api/v3/agents"), HttpWebRequest)
    myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json")
    myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-API-KEY", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    Dim myHttpWebResponse = CType(myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

    TextBox1.Text = myHttpWebResponse.ToString
```

Unfortunatly whatever I tried I get an error.
Can you help me out here?

Comment: Use `HttpClient`, not `HttpWebRequest`. What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: "whatever I tried I get an error." - **what error?**

Comment: .NET version is 4

Comment: Please be more specific than just "version 4" - there's almost a decade between 4.0 and 4.8. Are you targeting 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.2, 4.6.2, 4.7.2, 4.8?

Comment: Sorry, I ment 4.0, but I can increase the target to any version..

Comment: You should be targeting .NET Framework 4.8 and nothing earlier or older at this point.

Comment: Did.. Still can get things to work. Can you help me please?

Comment: _You haven't shared any details_ of the error message you're getting. Is it a compiler-error or runtime exception?

Comment: The error is: System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=The 'Accept' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name
  Source=System

Answer (score 0):

Got it worked.
They new code that works is:

```
Dim myHttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://app.atera.com/api/v3/agents/130"), HttpWebRequest)
myHttpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json"
'myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json")
myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-API-KEY", "XXXXXXXXXXXX")
Dim myHttpWebResponse = CType(myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Dim responseReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream)
Dim result As String = responseReader.ReadToEnd()

TextBox1.Text = result
```

End Sub